# Get a list of recently removed packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall

## Context

I have recently tried to figure out how to remove properly `postgresql` on bionic (Ubuntu server 18.04 `4.15.0-96-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux`) and after that, to install a new version starting with what is described here:

https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Everything went *almost* fine, except at a point where I wanted to clean and remove the previous version of postgresql related stuff. Because while removing `libpq-dev`, the system prompted for a quite large list of dependencies to remove. I blindly trusted it while entering [Y] but then I saw on the terminal output that some of them were probably necessary such as `libgeos` or `libpng`, were probably useful for other tools on the system.

I think I cannot find a place where I can find the recent terminal outputs (where I would be able to figure out each one of these removed packages) am I right? Note that I was using [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), which by default doesn't have much scrolling capabilities.

## Question

In that case, is there somewhere a list of packages that have been recently removed / uninstall with `apt-get`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory `/var/log/apt` contains the logs that will help you. Consult `history.log` and `term.log` for the details.

Here's an example removal from `history.log`

```
Start-Date: 2020-04-06  17:21:27
Commandline: apt-get autoremove
Requested-By: user (1000)
Remove: linux-image-5.3.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.3.0-42.34~18.04.1), linux-headers-5.3.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.3.0-42.34~18.04.1), linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.3.0-42.34~18.04.1), linux-headers-5.3.0-42:amd64 (5.3.0-42.34~18.04.1), linux-modules-5.3.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.3.0-42.34~18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-04-06  17:21:44
```

Comment: Even with the date- and time-stamps, that's really a great file!

Comment: @s.k I am glad it helped you and I hope you get your system fixed.

Comment: Another option is `zgrep -e "status not-installed " /var/log/dpkg.log* | grep 2020-03` to know which packages were removed in March 2020.

Comment: `zgrep` allows the user to search older, archived, dpkg log files.

Comment: @DKBose thanks, I learned something. I had never looked at the dpkg logs.